# SCREEN_OFF BroadcastReceiver is not working

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, screen-off

This is my code.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction("com.my.ACTION");
        intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);

        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    }

    ...

    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if ("com.my.ACTIOIN".equals(action)) {
                updateMessageInformation(intent);
                updateDialog();
            } else if (Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF.equals(action)) {
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
    ...
}
```

`com.my.ACTION` is detected and working correctly

But, `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF(android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF)` is not detected when the screen turn off.

This `Activity` is start from `Service`(start from other receiver).

What would I have anything wrong?

Comment: Do you unregister on onDestroy? Maybe the activity is destroyed before the intent is sent so it can't be received by the activity?

Comment: I unregister the receiver on onStop.

Comment: @galex Thank you. Moving the unregister to onDestroy, it work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `unregister` to `onDestroy`. When screen turn off, `onStop` is calling.

Reference to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

If the activity is no longer visible, `onStop` method is called.

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
}
```